# Merging Objects of different types

Tags: c#

I have two objects (WS.Customer and EF.Customer).  The reason for this is my vendor didn't expose all of the fields in their object (WS.Customer) and I need to insert and update into those fields.

I need to merge WS.Customer -> EF.Customer and later merge EF.Customer -> WS.Customer.  EF.Customer will have some extra fields that WS.Customer won't have, but when the field names match - I want the values merged.

I also only want to merge values where the destination field is null, empty, or a default value in case of a Guid.

I know I could use to Linq to query each object and build the other, but is there a less verbose way of doing things?  I have some other objects I need to use this approach for and don't feel like spending a weeks typing away.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean if ws.customer has fields-name,id,account,etc..-and ef.customer does not have for example id and account,you would like to insert them?

Comment: I dont know if this is what your looking for but have a look at the ExpandoObject class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of the available object-to-object mappers library like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) or [EmitMapper](http://emitmapper.codeplex.com/). They will take care of copying the data in both directions and skip fields if properly configured. For example with EmitMapper your code might look like this:

```
ObjectMapperManager.DefaultInstance
                   .GetMapper<WS.Customer, EF.Customer>(<your configuration object here>)
                   .Map(customerSource, customerDestination);
```

Comment: An alternative to AutoMapper is [ValueInjecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com). Here's a good SO question about [AutoMapper vs ValueInjecter](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4663577/9664) as well.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "merged"? I guess you need to "translate" from one instance to another, i.e. copy values when name and type of property matches. Please have a look at the implementation provided in ServiceStack, the extension method of object - TranslateTo method:  https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Common/ReflectionExtensions.cs#L31