# Automapper vs Value Injecter Performance and Flexiblitiy as of 2014

Tags: valueinjecter, automapper-3

From Automapper and Value Injecter which one is the fastest, which one is the flexible one? as of 2014 (today) not the evaluation of the past

Answer (score 0):

if your worried about performance you can use the SmartConventionInjection, which learns the matches between pairs of types and works faster because of that, also it doesn't uses the value of the property in the matching algorithm ( most times you don't need that)
you can see it here:

**http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SmartConventionInjection**

there are some speed tests as well

for differences, flexibility, see this question: [AutoMapper vs ValueInjecter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663577/automapper-vs-valueinjecter)